# jquery submit() form to current page with email validator

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I'm using a basic javascript email validation function and am trying to use jQuery to submit the form if conditions are met.  However, the `submit()` function doesn't seem to be running for the email validation is met.

**HTML**

```
<form id="profile" action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" id="email">\
    <span class="error" id="email_err">Email address not valid.</span>
    //Other Form data
</form>
<div id="form-submit">Submit</div>
```

**jQuery/Javascript**

```
function IsEmail(email) {
    var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
    return regex.test(email);
}

jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    $('#form-submit').click(function(){
        var email = $('#email').val();
        if(!IsEmail(email)){
            $('#email_err').show();
            $('#email').focus();
        }else{
            $('#profile').submit();
        }
    });
}
```

Now all I want it to do is catch the email validation.  Actual form submittal and data writing I would like to handle as I have it set up now where the PHP for writing the data is on the current page (`action=""`).  Originally, it was an actual form submit button but I wanted to try and validate the email without page refresh.

I figure my understanding of the `submit()` function might be off-point, as what I'm reading seems like it's just a listener for a form submit, but doesn't actually submit the form itself.  Is this correct or do I just have a flub up somewhere?

Comment: Looks like `mls_email` is undefined. Did you mean just `email`?

Comment: You are right. .submit() does 'submit' the form. What precisely is your question?

Comment: @WillM: Sorry, missed when ported over, it is supposed to be just `email`.  When the `else` condition is met, the form is not submitting.  Console doesn't post any errors.  I would like the `submit()` to `POST` the data as it would with a PHP form, including refresh the page.  I was just hoping tha JS/jQ would catch the email validation and then submit the form as if someone would have pressed a `<form>` submit element.

Comment: Okay. Make sure to have a set form `action`.

Comment: Well I want the action to go to the current page.  Typically to do this, action is left blank.  Will that not work with `submit()`?

Comment: @tPlummer You are missing the closing ");" in the last line. That's probably causing the error. Let me know if this works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're just validating your form, you can simply return `true` or `false` if the form is valid or not.

Some variant of:

```
$("#profile").submit(function() {
  var email = $('#email').val();
  if (!IsEmail(email)) {
    ...
    return false; // Form will not submit
  }
  ...
  return true; // Form will submit as usual
});
```

Make sure you use `<input type="submit" />` since you're attaching directly to the submit event.

Comment: Ok, so without the `<input type="submit">`, the form wasn't being submitted.  The `.submit()` function listens for the submit action and then either submits the form or does other stuff.  Thanks!